# How to get TableViewerColumn from tableViewer?

Tags: java, jface, tableviewer

I need to get the `TableViewerColumn[]` from tableViewer ( jface)

I need it to update the the `setEditingSupport`.

I tried this code

```
private TableViewerColumn[] getTableViewerColumns(TableViewer tableViewer) {
    TableColumn[] columns = tableViewer.getTable().getColumns();
    TableViewerColumn[] viewerColumns = new TableViewerColumn[columns.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        TableColumn tableColumn = columns[i];
        viewerColumns[i] = (TableViewerColumn) tableColumn.getData(Policy.JFACE + ".columnViewer"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }
    return viewerColumns;
}
```

It is working but I thought maybe there is an easy or classic way to get the TableViewerColumn.

Could you advise me on different way?

Comment: The column viewer key `Policy.JFACE + ".columnViewer"` is definitely not part of the defined API and may change in future. Why is it not possible to set the editing support when the table viewer is created?

Comment: I need to do it dyamic. In some case i need that the colum will be read only and in some case editable

Comment: `EditingSupport` has a `canEdit` method so you can always set the support and use that method.

Comment: How i can the editsupport not at creation of the table

Comment: How i can get the editsupport not in creation of the view

Comment: You should be providing your own class derived form EditingSupport. Look at [Eclipe JFace Table - Advanced](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJFaceTableAdvanced/article.html)

Comment: But i create the.class and did the set. Could you please show me an example how i can set editsupport not in the setinput of tableviewer

Comment: I need to do it in diffrerent stage that the data is exist and when I press on the button then I want to change the column